# Use RVM Ruby instead of MAMP Ruby

Tags: ruby, macos, rvm, mamp, iterm2

I've used RVM to install the latest stable version of Ruby, however, I can't set it to be the default version. Running `which ruby` always returns the path of Ruby installed with MAMP on my system eg `/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/ruby`

I've tried various rvm commands with no effect. I'd rather not have to run an rvm use command every time I open my terminal.

I'm using oh-my-zsh and iTerm2 if it makes a difference.

Comment: Is it activated on login? See https://rvm.io/rvm/install. Did you check everything in the zsh guide? https://rvm.io/integration/zsh. Do your projects have individual configurations? https://rvm.io/workflow/projects and https://rvm.io/workflow/rvmrc.

Comment: RVM is all activated and functional at login. I've checked those guides and nothing addresses the issue I'm having. I simply can't make the RVM Ruby stick as my default - it reverts to MAMP's install every time.

Comment: Then MAMP must be ending up in the path before the rvm stuff; update your question to include your path in a new shell and the results of running `which ruby` at the least. It's unclear from the MAMP docs what steps are taken during its install, but it sounds like you checked the Ruby box https://documentation-4.mamp.info/en/MAMP-PRO-Mac/Languages/Ruby/.

Comment: The result of running `which ruby` is already in my question. I've also come across the MAMP docs you've linked to and do not have the checkbox ticked.

Comment: What's your path?

Comment: Macs treat most terminal shells as login shells, so unless you post the relevant sections of your `~/.profile` and all your `~/.z*` scripts you're unlikely to get much help. Zsh has a lot of different startup scripts, and how you start your shell matters a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Dave Newton suggested, this smells like a `PATH` issue, but in the case of MAMP, it's also an `alias` issue.

If you open `~/.profile` and `~/.zprofile`, in one of them you will probably see these lines:

```
alias erb='/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/erb'
alias gem='/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/gem'
alias irb='/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/irb'
alias rake='/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/rake'
alias rdoc='/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/rdoc'
alias ri='/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/ri'
alias ruby='/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/ruby'
alias rails='/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/rails'
```

You'll want to remove them all, save the file, then quit and restart iTerm2.

If you don't know how to open and edit dotfiles, read my guide that explains various ways to [read and edit dotfiles on a Mac](https://www.moncefbelyamani.com/5-ways-to-open-hidden-files-on-your-mac/?utm_source=stackoverflow).

If removing those aliases doesn't fix it, then it's a `PATH` issue.

For your Mac to know about a command or other executable program, it has to be told where to look for it. It wouldn't be efficient for the computer to search the entire hard drive for the program.

Instead, it looks in a specific list of locations, which are stored in an environment variable called `PATH`, separated by a colon. You can view this list by running this command in your terminal:

```
echo $PATH
```

When you install new programs, such as Ruby, they might get installed in a location that is not already included in the `PATH`. If you don't add this new location to the `PATH`, the computer won't know to look for it there, and so it thinks it doesn't exist.

Similarly, if the location of the new program **did** get added to the `PATH`, but you have another location for the same program **earlier** in the `PATH`, then it will always use the first one it finds.

Most Ruby version managers use a script to automatically update the `PATH`, and they instruct you to add a line to your shell file to call that script, or they might add it for you. That line should come after any modifications of `PATH`.

It's been a while since I've used RVM (I no longer recommend it), but I think it's supposed to automatically add this line to your shell file:

```
source $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm
```

Assuming you installed RVM properly, here's what I would try:

1. Open your shell file. It should be `~/.zshrc` if you're using oh-my-zsh.
2. Look for any lines that start with `export PATH=`, and if they mention `/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/ruby`, remove that directory from the `PATH`. Also make sure any `PATH` lines come before the lines added by RVM.
3. Quit and restart iTerm2

If you don't see any RVM-related lines in `~/.zshrc` or `~/.zprofile` or `~/.profile`, then RVM was not properly installed.

If you really want to use RVM, try uninstalling and reinstalling it. If all you care about is having a working Ruby environment, I would recommend chruby and ruby-install. You can install them by following my [step-by-step guide to install Ruby on Mac](https://www.moncefbelyamani.com/how-to-install-xcode-homebrew-git-rvm-ruby-on-mac/?utm_source=stackoverflow).

Comment: Thank you for this. For what it's worth I had checked/actioned all the steps you mentioned with no solution. In the end I chose to uninstall RVM and follow your install instructions using cheruby and ruby-install.